# Finding a common string in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following data in a database:

```
0203020308260226
020302030826022633
02030203082602263332
0203020308270201
0203020308270222
0203020308290218
02030203082902180208
0203020308290224
02030203082902240208
```

I wanted to create a query which will pass a value of

> '030203082'

and it will display all the following records.

```
0203020308260226
020302030826022633
02030203082602263332
0203020308270201
0203020308270222
0203020308290218
02030203082902180208
0203020308290224
02030203082902240208
02030203082902240208
```

But if I pass

> '0302030829999'

it should also return me following 
result because at least 80% matches.

```
0203020308260226
    020302030826022633
    02030203082602263332
    0203020308270201
    0203020308270222
    0203020308290218
    02030203082902180208
    0203020308290224
    02030203082902240208
    02030203082902240208
```

I have tried this query

```
select * from table where columnA like '%02%' and columnA like '%03%'
columnA like '%02%' and columnA like '%08%' and  columnA like '%31%'
and columnA like '%99%' and columnA like '%99%'
```

Comment: **What is your question?** My guess: "For a nine-character substring, help me complete a query that returns all records where `ColumnA` contains that substring. For a thirteen character substring, return records that contain... at least ten characters from the substring?"

Comment: Relational databases are not suited to this type of string manipulation.  You will need to write your own function for such a comparison.

Comment: 80% is totally unclear. What is percent of match for 'ZZ123AB678XYZ' and '1234567890' for example?

Comment: I need similarity level 90% of above. I wanted to get all the results which has these words even without following sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand your question fully, but you could use the [`DIFFERENCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx) function, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE DIFFERENCE('0302030829999', column) = 4;
```

Comment: Never used this function though it was applied since SQL Server 2008. Simple and clear, thanks.

Comment: Dear Chris,
Thank you for sharing.
 select DIFFERENCE('3014021033033026330819','0819');
It also returns 4. I am receiving so many results. Which is not I want. I wanted to get minimum results which similarity is 90% or more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching a word with specific length in a column,then try with the below query.

```
  SELECT *
   FROM YourTable
   WHERE columnA like '%'+LEFT('0302030829999',9)+'%'
```

Comment: This doesnt work for me :( I am sorry and thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

This can be a starting point

```
DECLARE @SearchKey VARCHAR(100) = '0302030829999'
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE columnA LIKE '%' + @SearchKey +'%'        -- Exact match
    OR columnA LIKE '%' + LEFT(@SearchKey,LEN(@SearchKey)*0.8) +'%'         -- 80% from start
    OR columnA LIKE '%' + RIGHT(@SearchKey,LEN(@SearchKey)*0.8) +'%'        -- 80% from end
```

Hope it helps